# How do I return an array of object references with a specific length?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of object references with a size of 100. The array is filled with 4 object references while the rest of it is empty. What I want to do is return the array with only those 4 references. I tried creating a new array and copying the references into it, but then I always get an error saying the array is null when I try to invoke the method. Here's the code:

```
public Robots[] getRobots() {
        for(int i = 0; i < robots.length; i++) {
            if(robots[i] != null)
                count++;
        }
        Robots[] newRobots = new Robots[count];
        newRobots = Arrays.copyOfRange(robots, 0, count);
        return newRobots;
    }
```

Comment: post a [mcve].  We don't see where robots, count are defined and assigned values.

Comment: I suggest you use a `List` instead of an array. A list has a dynamic size for only the number of elements it contains. If you insist on using an array, you will need to provide more details, including a [mcve] and the exact error message you are asking about.

Comment: `Arrays.copyOfRange(robots, 0, count);` - that will give you an array of 4 (if there are 4 non-null element) from the very beginning of the array and they might be `null`

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you need to fix 2 errors:

1. clear the count variable
2. don't assume that all not null objects are at the beginning

here is the fixed code:

```
public Robots[] getRobots() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < robots.length; i++) {
        if(robots[i] != null)
            count++;
    }
    Robots[] newRobots = new Robots[count];
    
    count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < robots.length; i++) {
        if(robots[i] != null)
            newRobots[count++] = robots[i];
    }
    return newRobots;
}
```